# Vim delete all lines that has only one letter

Tags: vim

In Vim is it possible to delete lines that has only one letter?

For example

```
This
is
an
x
z
example
c
```

would turn into

```
This
is
an
example
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: You may be able to get better support at [VIM Stackexchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
:g/^.$/d
```

`:` — switch to the command line;

`g` — run a global command over all lines;

`/^.$/` — find a line that has exactly one character; beginning of the line, any character, end of the line;

`d` — delete the line.

Comment: how do I tweak this if I wanted to make it work for lines that has only (2) characters, or only 3 character, etc.?

Comment: Please read http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#search-pattern A dor (`.`) means any single character. For 2 or 3 character you can use 2 or 3 dots: `...`. Or counters: [`.\{2,3\}`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/\{) means "2 or 3".